# I am facing a problem in redirecting my angular js controller to c# controller.Below is my scrip controller code and c# controller code

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Dear Community,
               I am facing a problem in redirecting my angular js controller to c# controller.Below is my scrip controller code and c# controller code.Am i making any mistakes in url or is there any routing needed to take my angular controller to c# controller.When the controller is hit,it calls error callback with error alert instantly.please provide me with a solution.

**angular controller code:**

```
var httpTimeout = 1800000;
var httpTimeoutSearch = 3600000;
angular.module('MyApp', [])
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.Login = function () {
        if ($scope.username != null && $scope.username != "") {
            if ($scope.password != null && $scope.password != "") {
                try {
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '/Account/Maxi',
                        data: { Username: $scope.username, Passord: $scope.password },
                        timeout: httpTimeout,
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        alert("sucess");
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert("error");
                    });
                }
                catch (ex)
                { alert(ex); }
            }
        }

    }
}]);
```

**My C# Controller code:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Maxi(LoginModel data, string returnUrl)
{
    string strReturn = "";
    string ConStr = "";
    string Code = "";
    if (data.UserName != null)
   {
       if (data.Password != null)
       {


           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           SqlParameter[] parameters =
            {  

             new SqlParameter( "@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20) { Value = data.UserName } ,
             new SqlParameter("@Roll_No", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = data.Password  } ,



            };
           ConStr = "Data Source=" + "192.168.1.9" + ";Initial Catalog=" + "MyFistDataBase" + ";User id=" + "sa" + ";Password=" + "123" + ";";
           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
           {
               using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Maxi", con))
               {
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                   cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                   da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                   da.Fill(ds);
               }
           }

           string errmsg = "";

           if (errmsg != "")
           {
               Code = "0"; strReturn = errmsg;
           }
           else
           {
               if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
               {
                   if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                   {
                       Code = "1";

                       foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                       {
                           strReturn += dr[0].ToString();
                       }
                       if (strReturn == "1")
                       {
                           Console.Write("Updated");
                       }

                   }
                   //TripDT = TripDT.ToShortDateString();
               }

           } 
       } 
   }
    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first this first you need to correct your spelling mistakes in code that is BIG mistake in programming.
Try this type of data
C# class like this

```
 public class EmployeeInfo
    {
       [Key]
        public int EmpNo { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

js object like this

```
 var Employee = {
            EmpNo: $scope.EmpNo,
            EmpName: $scope.EmpName,
            Salary: $scope.Salary,
        };
```

http part change like this

```
 $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/Account/Maxi",
            data: Employee
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        alert("sucess");
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert("error");
            });

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Maxi(EmployeeInfo emp)
{
     your code here
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I have made the required change you have made but still the angular controller returns error call back. try {
                                    $http({
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        data: obj,
                                        url: '/Account/Maxi',

Comment: i have edit about answer for you you can try this and change as you want.